# javascript and php regex to allow only letters, numbers, full stops, asterisks, underscores and dashes

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I use this only for letters, numbers underscore and dash

```
var regexp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/;
```

and

```
$test = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]$/s', '', $ebay_username);
```

I need to filter js and php for ebay usernames.

Comment: `.` and `*` are special symbols and therefore should be escaped with \

Comment: `-` is used as range, to use it literally escape it or move it to the end `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+$/`

Comment: @u_mulder Nope, not in character class

Comment: @Tushar ok, thanks, will be aware

Comment: Take a close look at the `^`, it is in different positions when comparing the expressions. If not sure, wheter or not yours is correct, why not try it with sample data?

Comment: @kingkero the regex is not complete

Comment: @Tushar: you don't need to escape the hyphen in a character class after a range of characters in javascript and php. So writing `[0-9-_]` is correct.

Comment: The PHP test will only match the *last character* of the username if it's not a letter, number dash or underscore.

Comment: I guess `/^[a-zA-Z0-9-.*_]+$/` and `'/[^a-zA-Z0-9-.*_]/'` is what you need. Casimir is right, @Tushar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-.*_]+$/; // for JS
$test = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-.*_]/', '', $ebay_username); // for PHP
```

The main idea is to just add the symbols you need to the character class. Also, the `$` anchor is preventing from removing all the unwanted characters from the string anchoring the match at string end.

About the hyphen: it is after a range inside a character class and is thus parsed as a literal `-` symbol. As best practice, it should be put at the end of the character class so as not to have to escape it (though it will not work in [ElasticSearch](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-syntax) where it still should be escaped at the end of the character class, but not at its start).